# Asus Laptop Speakers Sound Under Water

Tags: audio, windows-11, speakers, asus-laptop

I just bought an **Asus ROG Strix 17 (G533ZS)** and installed **Windows 11** on it (saw that all the drivers on the Asus page for this specific model are only Windows 11 available). Anyway, I am having some sound problems, specifically it is just **the speakers** (it works well if I connect headphones - wired or Bluetooth, external speakers to it etc.). The internal speakers sound as if the laptop is under water or somehow like in a cinema with surround sound. I have to turn the volume very high in order to hear properly (the voices in the movies, games) but even then it still sound horrible.

What I tried so far:

- Reinstalling the driver & updating it
- Turn off spatial audio and audio surround in `Sound Properties` of the speaker
- In the Properties window for the speakers, in the `Enhancements` tab I checked the `Disable all enhancements`
- I also made sure the volume is properly set, not muted etc
- Tried looking into Dolby app, no change there affected the quality of the speakers output

However, none of this worked. Has anyone faced similar issues and found a solution? I can't seem to find any way out of it, and it is quite annoying when wanting to watch/play something and the speakers are completely useless. Thank you!

Edit (adding pictures of my setup):
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd guess the audio is routing as 5.1 rather than being correctly summed to stereo. Can you post pictures of your setup?

Comment: @Tetsujin Added pictures with my setup. If any other pictures are needed, please tell me

Comment: You're not the only one, I found others complaining about exactly the same "underwater" sound. According to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ZephyrusG15/comments/p79ece/awful_speaker_sound_quality/) the remedy is updating Asus Framework Service (click "Continue this thread").

Comment: @Peregrino69 Could not find any update for the Asus Framework Service in Armory Crate. Tried reinstalling it. Then, according to that thread, setting the boot sound back on seems to make the sound a little bit better, but it still seems a little bit off. Hopefully there will be a proper fix at some point...

Comment: I also found references to the same in Asus' own forums. I think you should drop the question there also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After other attempts, I finally managed to fix the issue and I will write an answer for others that might encounter this. Turns out the audio bus driver was not installed correctly (something was corrupt regarding the driver, I suppose, as I had a yellow warning sign on it in the **System devices** under **Device Manager** and the message listed below).

> Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required
> for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have
> installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might
> be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)

I found the solution on [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/fixed-intelr-smart-sound-technology-intelr-sst-oed/00485b71-188b-4af7-a212-326badab1084) Microsoft thread. However, to write the exact solution here as well: I uninstalled the two devices (located under **System devices** in the **Device Manager**) mentioned in the link (**Intel(R) Smart Sound Technology (Intel(R) SST) Audio Controller driver** and the **Intel(R) Smart Sound Technology (Intel(R) SST) OED**) and while doing so I also deleted the drivers for them (checked the box in the modal window that appeared). After this, I restarted my computer and the sound was working properly and no functionality was lost (I can still external devices as well). I hope this will help anyone else facing his issue.